# Move only directories and not files in Unix OS

Tags: unix

I had a directory with many files and sub-directories. To move only the sub-directories, I just learned you can use:

`ls -d BASEDIR/*/ | xargs -n1 -I% mv % TARGETDIR/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use find?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv '{}' /tmp \;
```

`-maxdepth 1` makes sure find won't go deeper than current directory
`-type d` tells find to only find directories
`-exec` execute a command with the result of the find referenced by `{}`

In my opinion a cleaner solution and it also works better then using xargs when you have files with white space or tabs in them.

Comment: Thanks. I like your point about not need to be concerned about tabs and white space. I wanted to move only directories though, so I will amend yours for that below:

Comment: Ah sorry, I guess I got a bit confused :) `-type d` in that case is your friend then

Answer (score 11):

I use the following:

```
$ mv ./*/ DirToMoveTo
```

For example:
Say I wanted to move all directories with "Old" in the name to a folder called "***Old_Dirs***" on ***/data***. 
The command would look like this:

```
mv ./*Old*/ /data/
```

Answer (score 3):

With a file structure like this:

```
/dir2move2
/dir
  /subdir1
  /subdir2
  index.js
```

To move only the sub directories and not the files you could just do:

`mv ./dir/*/ ./dir2move2`

Comment: Simple and straightforward

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use the same command for moving a file but put a slash after the name of the subdirectory

```
    sudo mv */ path/to/destination 
    sudo mv subdir/ path/to/subdirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution:

```
find BASEDIR/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec mv '{}' TARGETDIR \;
```